# Eclipse Plugin: OutlineView

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-emf, eclipse-gmf

A have a plugin and I want to overwrite default Outline view but I want to use some features from default Outline(Overview), where can I get the source Code of default OutlineView implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the eclipse Plug-in Spy for that. It will tell you details of the plugin for any view. http://eclipse.dzone.com/articles/eclipse-34-hidden-treasures